# 'fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/gh-pages' after running:git push origin :gh-pages

Tags: git, github-pages

My gh-pages didn't update correctly so I decided to remove the old version and push new copy.
Some steps I took:

**1** I found how to remove gh-pages here:

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8512/how-to-remove-github-pages

**2** Then I run `git push origin :gh-pages` Gh-pages was successfully deleted.

**3** Next step I ran: `git push origin gh-pages`
I got :

```
'fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/gh-pages'
```

**4** Tried to create a gh-pages locally then push again.
**Only show README.md.**

**5** Tried to `npm rm -rf node_modules/gh-pages/ && npm install`
from https://github.com/tschaub/gh-pages/issues/17

But the problem still there, the same fatal error.

**Extra step:**
I also configured my publishing source settings-> "GitHub Pages"->'Master', but it didn't seem to work.

https://docs.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site#creating-your-site

Did I do something wrong? The gh-pages was successfully created once no drama by running "npm run deploy" before. So I don't understand what's wrong.
Any idea will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finanlly figured out a way to re-publish the gh-pages, that's

```
git push origin :gh-pages
```

next step, in the local branches, build another branch named: `gh-pages`
then current branch points to `gh-pages`,
run `git push -u origin gh-pages`.
(Here I also ran `npm run build` first to build the `build` folder locally, and it reminded to run `npm run deploy` as scripted in `package.json` file.)

After last few steps it didn't show `fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/gh-pages` again.

However, this may only display the `README.md`，even in the `setting` the `source` already pointed to the `gh-pages`, so I switched between the `master` and `gh-pages` branches ,even tried the `/doc` and `/(root)` folder, and one of it finanlly worked.

Answer (score 6):

This is how I resolved it

I had my deploy script before
`"deploy": "gh-pages -d build"`

I changed it to
`"deploy": "gh-pages-clean gh-pages -d build"`

Then, I ran `npm run deploy`

After that, I changed my deploy script to the previous state
`"deploy": "gh-pages -d build"`

Now, `npm run deploy`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and resolved by removing gh-pages from node_modules and package.json file. Reinstall it by `npm install gh-pages --save-dev`

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/tschaub/gh-pages/issues/17#issuecomment-299775061), you can use the `gh-pages-clean`command for that.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score -1):

1.create a repository and push the project
2.use @Yuvaraj's answer
will published successfully.

Comment: please expand this into a full answer post. see also [/help/referencing](/help/referencing)